# The right landing page is not ranking

Tags: seo, keywords, google-ranking, pages

I have been trying to rank the right landing page for some specific keywords. But the page struggles to rank for the specific keywords. They are only ranking for the home page. The landing page is indexed in google, so got no issues.

Is it a good practice to add internal linking from the target keyword from the landing page itself? So that google can know which is the right page for the target keywords?

Comment: "**from** the landing page itself" - Just to point out that you are specifically asking about  links "from" the landing page you are wanting to rank. However, the opposite would generally be far more beneficial... "internal linking from the target keyword **to** the landing page".

Answer (score 1):

Here, you can try the following methods:

1. Use your target keywords in the meta title or meta description or maybe both according to your wish and content relevancy.
2. As you asked in the question about internal linking, yes it is one of the best and most followed way to do so and I recommend you to do the internal linking by using the target keywords.
3. Last but not least, make some backlinks where the  tag contains your target keywords in the text.

Comment: "in the meta title or meta description" - Note that keywords in the "meta description" do not directly help with _ranking_. However, they can help with click-through rates _if_ the meta description is shown in the search results (but Google often generates its own _description_ in the search results, particularly if the meta description is not particularly on point).

Answer (score 1):

After making a landing there are different signals that you should give the page for indexing with the desired keyword:
(In all the following list be aware of stuffing or overdoing)

1. Relevant title and description.
2. Relevant H1 and H2s containing your keyword
3. Relevant content with at least 700 words (due to my experience)
4. If it is a listing of products(PLP) try to include your keyword in cards titles(H2 tag for card titles is recommended)
5. Internal linking with exact(Exactly exact) keywords from blog/main pages.(Review your existing links too.)
6. Give some off-page signal with desired keyword(Caution on this/should be done with experience)